# Problem how to get the information of a message sent by Telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I brought an easy example to better understand my problem.

I have these codes that you enter name and text to then get the values with Get.

Once received the values, the program will send in a telegram bot created by me with a `sendMessage`.

`$chat_id =` to the chat id of the telegram bot I created.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])  && isset($_GET['message'])){
define ('url',"https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/");
$name = $_GET['name'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
$chat_id = 'TEST';
function invia($chat_id,$message = ''){
    $url=  url."sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&parse_mode=HTML&text=".$message;
    file_get_contents($url);
}




$message = urlencode("Hello $name this is the message :  $message");

invia($chat_id, $message);

}

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
  <br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" rows="6" cols="33"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Let’s write for example **Name**: "Lorenzo Poggi" and **Message**: "Hi, this is a test".

Once sent, I will receive the message directly in the chat of the telegram bot.

Now the question is this, but if in the `example.php` page, where I have all the updates of the telegram bot in question thanks to `setWebhook`, I would like to get the writing "is a test" from the text of the message sent previously with `sendMessage`, How can I do that?

Comment: "is there any way to extract the messages that you have sent by your bot?", is this your question? or explain your question in a more clear way

Comment: Yes, I want to extract the words "is a test" from the message that was sent to my bot telegram.

Answer (score 2):

The result of Telegram response should be something like this :

```
{
  "update_id": 901816057,
  "message": {
    "message_id": 36089,
    "from": {
      "id": 223110107,
      "first_name": "Ğąme",
      "last_name": "Ǿver!",
      "username": "GameO7er"
    },
    "chat": {
      "id": 223110107,
      "first_name": "Ğąme",
      "last_name": "Ǿver!",
      "username": "GameO7er",
      "type": "private"
    },
    "date": 1490493909,
    "text": "Hi, this is a test"
  }
}
```

You can log the response and try to decode it via this [website](https://www.10bestdesign.com/dirtymarkup/js/)
Then if you wanna to get/print message of users you should use this way :

```
function invia(){
    $url=  url."sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&parse_mode=HTML&text=".$message;
    $TelegramResult = file_get_contents($url);
    $UserText = $TelegramResult['message']['text']; // Hi, this is a test
}
```

as you can see `$UserText` contains the text that your user sent to the bot.

Let me if you have any question. also my Telegram id is shown in the above source so feel free to contact me.